# Detecting mysql support in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get info about mysql support with PHP. I need a code to detect if server have mysql support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (extension_loaded('mysqlnd')) // or 'mysql' or 'pdo_*'
   echo 'MYSQL extension is loaded';
```

you can also use:

```
if (function_exists('mysql_connect'))
   echo 'MYSQL functions are available';
```

Answer (score 2):

Save this as `info.php` (name not important though) and access it through a web browser. Amongst a bunch of other info, it will tell you whether PHP was compiled with MySQL or not.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 : only solution given that works independantly of the API. MySQLi and PDO exist!

Answer (score 1):

Do this in code with.

```
if (!function_exists('mysql_connect'))
{
  return 'MySQL not supported by PHP on this server!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (extension_loaded('mysql')) {
    echo "MySQL Installed";
} else {
    echo "MySQL not installed";
}
```