# Check if PHP has been compiled --with-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting mysql support in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100885/detecting-mysql-support-in-php)

Is there a quick way to programmatically check whether this particular PHP installation has been compiled with support for MYSQL?

Comment: Do you mean phpinfo(); ?

Comment: phpinfo just renders a crapload of HTML. Surely there should be a way to just check the supported features from within my PHP script.

Comment: at the command prompt, type `php -m`. Programmatically: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are actually multiple modules supporting MySQL (mysql, mysqli, pdo_mysql, ...).  [MySQLi (improved)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is generally recommended for more complete support of MySQL5 features versus the original mysql module. [PDO (PHP data objects)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is a database abstraction layer that provides an object oriented data abstraction.

You can use `function_exists()` per the previous comments if you want to check for the existence of a specific function per module (mysql_connect, mysqli_connect, ...).

Alternatively, you can use the PHP function [`extension_loaded()`](http://php.net/extension_loaded) to check for the extension itself (module name matching the output from phpinfo() ):

```
<?php
    if (extension_loaded('mysql') or extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
        // Looking good
    }
?>
```

From a command line prompt, you can list all compiled-in modules with:

```
php -m
```

If you're on a unix-ish system, use `grep` to filter the output to MySQL-related modules:

```
php -m | grep -i mysql
```

If you're on Windows, use `findstr` to filter the output to MySQL-related modules:

```
php -m | findstr -i mysql
```

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 8):

```
if (function_exists('mysql_connect')) ...
```

Comment: Agreed, but if there's a function named `mysql_connect`, it's likely *the* `mysql_connect` or something that works exactly the same. :)

Comment: Well, I just was saying so. And also I found the duplicate of this question which I think is worth to point to, too.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for [phpinfo();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

This shows the info about PHP configuration.

> phpinfo — Outputs information about PHP's configuration

Comment: Programmatically. Anyway, the other answers answered this particular question.

Comment: @qdot It's still programmatically, since it's a function and all that. But I get what you mean ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.
Just check if one of the `mysql_*` functions exists, say `mysql_connect`:

```
if (function_exists("mysql_connect")) {
  echo "compiled using --with-mysql\n";
}
```