# Fatal Error: ezSQL_mysql requires mySQL Lib to be compiled and or linked in to the PHP engine

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error, url-shortener, yourls

I'm attempting to get the link shortening PHP scripts [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) working on my basic web server running Lubuntu 12.04.

I have a MySQL database created and PHP5 installed. When I attempt to access the administration interface for YOURLS in a browser, I am presented with the following message:

```
Fatal Error: ezSQL_mysql requires mySQL Lib to be compiled and or linked in to the PHP engine
```

I'm very new to MySQL and PHP, so I don't know how to approach this problem. Could you point me in the right direction on this?

(For a quick guide to setting up YOURLS, you can see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQ8R5CYSITU) to get the general idea.)

Comment: If you use php7 ensure you use ezSQL mysqli because mysql functions were removed in php7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the MySQL extension is loaded into PHP.ini, and has been compiled into PHP as well.

Comment: 1: ensure that the MySQL extension is loaded into php.ini ...

cat /etc/php5/cli/php.ini | grep MySQL
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
[MySQL]
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
[MySQLi]
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
; Size of a pre-allocated buffer used when sending commands to MySQL in bytes.

Comment: According to [this](http://ocaoimh.ie/2007/01/03/cannot-load-mysql-extension-please-check-your-php-configuration/), I should be seeing something like "extension=mysql.so" in the php.ini file. I don't see it there. Should I add it? If so, can it be added directly to the file?

Comment: 2: ensure that the MySQL extension has been compiled into PHP ... I don't really know how to go about doing this. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097531/check-if-php-has-been-compiled-with-mysql#comment14539564_11097531), I may be able to see loaded extensions using php -m:

php -m | grep mysql
mysql
mysqli
pdo_mysql

Could you advise on what I should attempt next? Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Install `mysql-devel` and `php-mysqli` packages

`yum install mysql-devel php-mysqli`

Names can change a bit as Ernest show's in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed your php server and mysql through yum, try to use yum to search for the relevant package.

For example, if you used "yum install php55", try "yum search php55", then look for something like "php55-mysqld". If found, install it "yum install php-mysqld". That will install the required module for PHP to interact with your mysql.

Answer (score -1):

Installing all php packages and its dependencies worked for me.

yum install php-*

Comment: As far as this can solve the problem, I discourage anybody to do this. there are tons of packages who start with php-*.

This solves the problem, but is not the solution.

Answer (score -3):

finnaly i Found the solution 
just change this line > `class ezSQL_mysql extends ezSQLcore` in ez_sql_mysql.php

to `class ezSQL_mysqlx extends ezSQLcore`

:)